# Is there such a thing as a separable second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have a function $y''(x) = g(x)y(x)$.  Could I separate this by dividing by $y$ and then integrating?  i.e. $dy^2/y = g dx^2$ or maybe $y'/y\ dy = g (dx/dx) dx = g dx$?  If so, how does one integrate something like $dy^2$ or $y' dy$?  If not, how to solve this type of ODE?

Comment: Integrate it twice.